# JavaScript: Datatables serverside processing - change values before display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

For displaying my data in a table, I use the [dataTable](https://datatables.net) plugin. As I have a big amount of data, I use the serverside processing. My problem is, that I have some data fields in my obtained JSON, that I would like to change before i display it in the table.

**Example:** I get values, whether some equipment is available or not. This is written as "", 0 or 1 in datasbase, for displaying it I would like to convert these values to "Yes" or "No" or "N/A". 

 
To initialise the table I use the following code:

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax": "myurl",
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxDataProp":"",
    "deferRender": true,
    columns: [
    {data: 'attributes.0.value'},
    {data:'attributes.1.value'},
    {data:'attributes.2.value'},
    {data:'attributes.3.value'},
    {data:'attributes.4.value'}],
});
```

To bind the conerting function directly in the data array doesn't work (like

```
{data: convert(attributes.0.value)},
```

There are some parameters for the datatable plugin, which I tried, but I'm not sure, if they can solve my problems. This is an example from the documentation of the plugin:

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
     "ajax": {
         "url": "data.json",
         "data": function ( d ) {
             d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
         }
      }
 });
```

Can I use the data parameter to solve my problems (when I tried this, d is always empty) or it there another possibility to change my values before I integrate them in a table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* preprocess the JSON in an [**`ajax.dataSrc`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) function, but since you really just need to modify how the values are shown I would go for [**column rendering**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) :

```js
columns: [
   { data: 'attributes.0.value',
     render: function(data, type, row) {
        switch(data) {
           case '0' : return 'No'; break;
           case '1' : return 'Yes'; break; 
           default : return 'N/A'; break;
        }
   },
   { data: 'attributes.1.value' },
   { data: 'attributes.2.value' },
   { data: 'attributes.3.value' },
   { data: 'attributes.4.value' }
]
```

Use the above `render` method to each of the column values you need to convert.

Comment: Thank yout, that's exactly what I have been looking for :-)

Comment: `render` part becomes redundant if multiple columns have multiple display logic